# Spark SQL Stackoverflow

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm a newbie on spark and spark sql and I was trying to make the example that is on Spark SQL website, just a simple SQL query after loading the schema and data from a JSON files directory, like this:

```
import sqlContext.createSchemaRDD
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
val path = "/home/shaza90/Desktop/tweets_1428981780000"
val tweet = sqlContext.jsonFile(path).cache()

tweet.registerTempTable("tweet")
tweet.printSchema() //This one works fine


val texts = sqlContext.sql("SELECT tweet.text FROM tweet").collect().foreach(println)
```

The exception that I'm getting is this one:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError

    at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$append$1.apply(Parsers.scala:254)
at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$$anon$3.apply(Parsers.scala:222)
```

**Update**

I'm able to execute `select * from tweet` but whenever I use a column name instead of * I get the error.

Any Advice?

Comment: Which version of Spark are you using?

Comment: Sounds like this (unresolved) bug: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-4208

Comment: my version is  Spark 1.1.0

Comment: Do you recommend using another versions?

Comment: It is always worth trying the latest version. Also, the bug reads "Affects Version/s: 1.1.0" - it is possible that it disappeared in later versions.

Comment: Yes you should be using the 1.3.x version as Spark SQL main abstraction (SchemaRDD) changed a lot to DataFrame

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is [SPARK-5009](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-5009) and has been fixed in Apache Spark 1.3.0.

The issue was that to recognize keywords (like `SELECT`) with any case, all possible uppercase/lowercase combinations (like `seLeCT`) were generated in a recursive function. This recursion would lead to the `StackOverflowError` you're seeing, if the keyword was long enough and the stack size small enough. (This suggests that if upgrading to Apache Spark 1.3.0 or later is not an option, you can use `-Xss` to increase the JVM stack size as a workaround.)

Comment: What is -Xss? How can I change it?

Comment: It's thanks to stholzm for finding SPARK-4208 and Sean Owen for closing it as a duplicate of SPARK-5009 less than an hour ago :). `-Xss` is a `java` command line flag. For example `-Xss4M` will set stack size to 4 MB (I guess that should be enough). If you start the Spark application with `spark-submit`, I think you need to use the `--conf` flag to pass this other flag. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28166667/how-to-pass-d-parameter-or-environment-variable-to-spark-job.