# How to pass environment variables to spark driver in cluster mode with spark-submit

Tags: apache-spark, environment-variables

`spark-submit` allows to configure the executor environment variables with `--conf spark.executorEnv.FOO=bar`, and the Spark REST API allows to pass some environment variables with the `environmentVariables` field.
Unfortunately I've found nothing similar to configure the environment variable of the driver when submitting the driver with `spark-submit` in cluster mode:

```
spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster myapp.jar
```

Is it possible to set the environment variables of the driver with `spark-submit` in cluster mode?

Comment: I should have said that I'm using spark in standalone mode — no yarn or mesos

Comment: Did you find any way to do so eventually?

Answer (score 26):

On YARN at least, this works:

`spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster --conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.FOO=bar myapp.jar`

---

It's mentioned in http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#environment-variables that:

> Note: When running Spark on YARN in `cluster` mode, environment variables need to be set using the `spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.[EnvironmentVariableName]` property in your `conf/spark-defaults.conf` file.

I have tested that it can be passed with `--conf` flag for `spark-submit`, so that you don't have to edit global conf files.

Comment: For having the environment variable also on excutore you need also to add: `--conf spark.executorEnv.FOO=bar`

Comment: for `executorEnv` here is the [link to section](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#runtime-environment) and the [link to the option](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#:~:text=spark.executorEnv.) (this link only works on chromium based browsers)

Answer (score 10):

On Yarn in cluster mode, it worked by adding the environment variables in the spark-submit command using --conf as below-

**spark-submit --master yarn-cluster --num-executors 15 --executor-memory 52g --executor-cores 7 --driver-memory 52g --conf "spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.FOO=/Path/foo" --conf "spark.executorEnv.FOO2=/path/foo2" app.jar**

Also, you can do it by adding them in conf/spark-defaults.conf file.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the below Classification to set-up environment variables on executor and master node:

```
[   
  {
   "Classification": "yarn-env",
   "Properties": {},
   "Configurations": [
       {
         "Classification": "export",
         "Properties": {
             "VARIABLE_NAME": VARIABLE_VALUE,
         }
       }
   ]
 }
]
```

If you just set `spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.FOO = "foo"`, then the env variable won't be present on executor instances.

Comment: Classifications are an EMR (AWS) specific mechanism. the OP did not specify using EMR

Comment: Property key, value may not be `null` and total length may not exceed 1024.

Answer (score 4):

### For `deploy-mode cluster`

As previous answers mentioned, if you want to pass env variable to spark master, you want to use:

```
--conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.FOO=bar    // pass bar value to FOO variable
--conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.FOO=${FOO} // passing current FOO env variable
--conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.FOO2=bar2  // multiple variables are passed separately
```

Thanks [@juhoautio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41639629/1549135)

### For `deploy-mode client`

Even though its not mentioned in the question, if you are starting to doubt your skills and found this SO page in google I just wanted to reassure you.

When using `client` mode, all the ENV variables from your current SHELL are available for spark master. So basically:

```
export FOO=bar 
export FOO2=bar2
```

is definitely working, so if you can't access this value for some reason, it must be something else :-)

Answer (score 3):

Did you test with

```
--conf spark.driver.FOO="bar"
```

and then getting value with

```
spark.conf.get("spark.driver.FOO")
```

Comment: This is old, but for anyone reading later, the OP specifically asked about system environment variables. This is just a custom Spark Configuration value, which, while a totally valid alternative, doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, That is possible. What are the variables you need you could post that in spark-submit like you're doing?

```
spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster myapp.jar
```

Take variables from http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html and depends on your optimization use these. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28166667/how-to-pass-d-parameter-or-environment-variable-to-spark-job) could also be helpful.

I used to use in cluster mode but now I'm using in YARN so my variables are as follows: (Hopefully helpful)

```
hastimal@nm:/usr/local/spark$ ./bin/spark-submit --class  com.hastimal.Processing  --master yarn-cluster  --num-executors 15 --executor-memory 52g --executor-cores 7 --driver-memory 52g  --driver-cores 7 --conf spark.default.parallelism=105 --conf spark.driver.maxResultSize=4g --conf spark.network.timeout=300  --conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=4608 --conf spark.yarn.driver.memoryOverhead=4608 --conf spark.akka.frameSize=1200  --conf spark.io.compression.codec=lz4 --conf spark.rdd.compress=true --conf spark.broadcast.compress=true --conf spark.shuffle.spill.compress=true --conf spark.shuffle.compress=true --conf spark.shuffle.manager=sort /users/hastimal/Processing.jar Main_Class /inputRDF/rdf_data_all.nt /output /users/hastimal/ /users/hastimal/query.txt index 2
```

In this, my jar following are arguments of class.

> cc /inputData/data_all.txt /output /users/hastimal/
>   /users/hastimal/query.txt index 2

Comment: OP is asking about environment variables, but this answer appears to address how to configure java properties.