# Not able to set right memory options in Spark

Tags: scala, memory, apache-spark

I am training a LDA model on wikipedia articles(4 million docs, ~14GB data). I am running a scala script on one machine with ~98GB memory. I run the scala code in spark shell with following params:

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-shell --executor-memory 2G --driver-memory 25G --total-executor-cores 10 --conf spark.driver.maxResultSize=50g
```

Code snippet:

```
val lda = new LDA().setOptimizer(new OnlineLDAOptimizer()).setK(numTopics).setMaxIterations(maxIterations)

val ldaModel = lda.run(lda_countVector)
```

I get the following error when I execute lda.run():

```
    scala> val ldaModel = lda.run(lda_countVector)
16/06/30 12:53:45 WARN BLAS: Failed to load implementation from: com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeSystemBLAS
16/06/30 12:53:45 WARN BLAS: Failed to load implementation from: com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeRefBLAS
[Stage 21:==============================>                      (238 + 85) / 408]16/06/30 13:35:59 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 315.0 in stage 21.0 (TID 2803)
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3236)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:118)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:93)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:153)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.write(ObjectOutputStream.java:1853)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.write(ObjectOutputStream.java:709)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.writeByteBuffer(Utils.scala:183)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DirectTaskResult$$anonfun$writeExternal$1.apply$mcV$sp(TaskResult.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1204)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DirectTaskResult.writeExternal(TaskResult.scala:49)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeExternalData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1459)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1430)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:44)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:256)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have tried various settings for memory like increasing driver memory, increasing maxResultSize memory, executor memory etc, but I still get the same error. If I reduce maxResultSize below 40GB, then I get maxResultSize error.

Please help me figure out the right memory settings. What should be done for a typical application like this?

Thanks.

Comment: Depending on JRE version you should look more at JVM options `-Xmx` in particular.

Comment: --executor-memory 2G --driver-memory 25G looks weird. It makes more sense when using it in the opposite.

Comment: Thanks guys, I will try those.

Comment: @rockie-yang If I reduce the driver memory, I get out of memory exception and the spark logs suggest me to increase driver memory. I wonder if the run method of LDA returns results while it is computing. Why else would there be errors like OutOfMemory and maxResultSize exceeded? Any thought please?

Comment: It is too much data get to driver if the driver got OOM. Since you have 14G data, it could be issue related to partitions. Try to increase partition number to see what happens.

Comment: @PranavKulkarni I use Spark on YARN cluster, with [config] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37887168/how-to-pass-environment-variables-to-spark-driver-in-cluster-mode-with-spark-sub/37887851#37887851). I had a similar issue when I used to run in local mode. I resolve from this [blog](0x0fff.com/spark-architecture-shuffle/) and [next] (https://0x0fff.com/spark-memory-management/) . I used to run like `val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").set("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "8g").set("spark.executor.memory", "16g").set("spark.driver.memory", "8g")`. Also see your heap and JVM.

Answer (score 0):

In spark-shell you didn't provide a master url. This means that you run in local mode. So executor memory setting will be ignored. The number of cores will default the number of CPU-s. To be most conservative run with -master local[1]. This means only 1 core
You could increase the driver memory to 80G , also set spark.memory.storageFraction to 0.1. This takes memory used to cache Rdd's and gives more to the reducers.