# EMR cluster bootstrap + setting environment variables cluster-wise

Tags: pyspark, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr

I am trying to create an EMR cluster (through the command line) and give it some bootstrap actions and configurations file.

The aim is setting some `SPARK`/`Yarn` vars, and some other environment variables that should be used cluster-wise (so these env vars should be available on the master AND the slaves).

I am giving it a configurations file that looks like this:

```
[
 {
    "Classification": "yarn-env",
    "Properties": {},
    "Configurations": [
      {
        "Classification": "export",
        "Properties": {
          "appMasterEnv.SOME_VAR": "123",
          "nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled": "false",
          "executor.memoryOverhead": "5g"
        },
        "Configurations": [
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Classification": "spark-env",
    "Properties": {},
    "Configurations": [
      {
        "Classification": "export",
        "Properties": {
          "appMasterEnv.SOME_VAR": "123",
          "PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON": "python36",
          "PYSPARK_PYTHON": "python36",
          "driver.memoryOverhead": "14g",
          "driver.memory": "14g",
          "executor.memory": "14g"
        },
        "Configurations": [
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

However when I try to add some steps to the cluster, the step fails claiming it does not know about the environment variable `SOME_VAR`.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "..", line 9, in <module>.
  ..
    raise EnvironmentError
OSError
```

(The line number is where I am trying to use the environment var `SOME_VAR`)

Am I doing it the right way both for `SOME_VAR` and the other `Spark`/`Yarn` vars?

Thank you

Comment: you dont have to prefix the variable with "appMasterEnv".

Comment: check this answer  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37887168/how-to-pass-environment-variables-to-spark-driver-in-cluster-mode-with-spark-sub#answer-47558260

Answer (score 0):

Remove appMasterEnv in front of appMasterEnv.SOME_VAR, as user lenin suggested.

Use classification yarn-env to pass environment variables to the worker nodes.

Use classification spark-env to pass environment variables to the driver, with deploy mode client. When using deploy mode cluster, use yarn-env.