# Cant connect to a FTP server programmatically using Scala through a proxy server

Tags: scala, curl, proxy, ftp

i have this Scala code in order to connect to some FTP server:

```
import java.io.{File, FileOutputStream, InputStream}

import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.{FTPClient,FTPFile}
import scala.util.Try

final class FTP() {

private val client = new FTPClient

def login(username: String, password: String): Try[Boolean] = Try {
 client.login(username, password)
}

def connect(host: String): Try[Unit] = Try {
 client.connect(host)
 client.enterLocalPassiveMode()
}

def connected: Boolean = client.isConnected

def disconnect(): Unit = client.disconnect()

def canConnect(host: String): Boolean = {
 client.connect(host)
 val connectionWasEstablished = connected
 client.disconnect()
 connectionWasEstablished
}

def listFiles(dir: Option[String] = None): List[FTPFile] =
dir.fold(client.listFiles)(client.listFiles).toList

def connectWithAuth(host: String,
                  username: String = "anonymous",
                  password: String = "") : Try[Boolean] = {
for {
  connection <- connect(host)
  login      <- login(username, password)
} yield login
}

def cd(path: String): Boolean =
 client.changeWorkingDirectory(path)

def filesInCurrentDirectory: Seq[String] =
 listFiles().map(_.getName)

def downloadFileStream(remote: String): InputStream = {
 val stream = client.retrieveFileStream(remote)
 client.completePendingCommand()
 stream
}

def downloadFile(remote: String): Boolean = {
 val os = new FileOutputStream(new File(remote))
 client.retrieveFile(remote, os)
}

def uploadFile(remote: String, input: InputStream): Boolean =
 client.storeFile(remote, input)
}// end of final class


val myFTP = new FTP

val myBool : Try[Boolean] =   myFTP.connectWithAuth("MY_FTP_SERVER","USER","PASS")

println("Can connect? " + myBool)
```

When I run this code in a local spark-shell, I have this:

```
scala> val myFTP = new FTP
myFTP: FTP = $iwC$$iwC$FTP@1077598b

scala> 

scala> val myBool : Try[Boolean] = myFTP.connectWithAuth("MY_FTP_SERVER","USER","PASS")
myBool: scala.util.Try[Boolean] = Failure(java.net.UnknownHostException: MY_FTP_SERVER: nodename nor servname provided, or not known)

scala> println("Can connect? " + myBool)
Can connect? Failure(java.net.UnknownHostException: MY_FTP_SERVER: nodename nor servname provided, or not known)
```

If I export http_proxy variable in a shell, I can reach to the ftp server via curl, so, how can I programmatically set http_proxy variable using Scala?

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Alonso:spark-1.5.0-bin-hadoop2.6 aisidoro$ export http_proxy=socks5://MY_PROXY:1080
MacBook-Pro-de-Alonso:spark-1.5.0-bin-hadoop2.6 aisidoro$ curl MY_FTP_SERVER
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://MY_FTP_SERVER">here</a>.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Server at MY_FTP_SERVER Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

Thank you very much.

UPDATE 22 Dic 2016

I have tried to do this in the same spark-shell that I run the FTP class code:

```
scala> System.setProperty("http_proxy","socks5://MY_PROXY_SERVER:1080")
res0: String = null

scala> System.getProperty("http_proxy")
res1: String = socks5://MY_PROXY_SERVER:1080
```

with the same result, I cannot reach programmatically to this ftp server through a proxy server...

I also have tried to export JAVA_OPTS before running the spark-shell in the same terminal session, with the same result...

```
export JAVA_OPTS="Dhttp.proxyHost=socks5://MY_PROXY_HOST -Dhttp.proxyPort=1080"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the `http_proxy` environment variables are commonly used by `curl` and various other utilities, java has its own way of [specifying proxy settings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html). Since you're using a SOCKS proxy, try setting the socks proxy properties, e.g. if using command line/environment variables:

```
-DsocksProxyHost=MY_PROXY_HOST -DsocksProxyPort=1080
```

If using the spark shell, you may want to look at for example [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28166667/1298153) regarding passing these through.

The [Apache Commons FtpClient](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/javadocs/api-3.5/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html) also doesn't do anything to explicitly look at the environment variables, and uses [`socket.connect`](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/commons/proper/net/tags/NET_3_5/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.java?view=markup#l924) to connect to the the FTP server.

However, there is a [FTPHTTPClient](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/javadocs/api-3.5/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPHTTPClient.html) class that might be handy if you wanted to tunnel FTP traffic via a HTTP proxy, see the [example](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/xref/examples/ftp/FTPClientExample.html#L260) for details, but basically it's:

```
ftp = new FTPHTTPClient(proxyHost, proxyPort, proxyUser, proxyPassword);
```