# can't add alluxio.security.login.username to spark-submit

Tags: apache-spark, spark-submit, alluxio

I have a spark driver program which I'm trying to set the alluxio user for.

I read this post: [How to pass -D parameter or environment variable to Spark job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28166667/how-to-pass-d-parameter-or-environment-variable-to-spark-job) and although helpful, none of the methods in there seem to do the trick.

My environment:

```
- Spark-2.2
- Alluxio-1.4
- packaged jar passed to spark-submit
```

The spark-submit job is being run as root (under supervisor), and alluxio only recognizes this user.

Here's where I've tried adding "-Dalluxio.security.login.username=alluxio":

- spark.driver.extraJavaOptions in spark-defaults.conf
- on the command line for spark-submit (using --conf)
- within the sparkservices conf file of my jar application
- within a new file called "alluxio-site.properties" in my jar application

None of these work set the user for alluxio, though I'm easily able to set this property in a different (non-spark) client application that is also writing to alluxio.

Anyone able to make this setting apply in spark-submit jobs?

Comment: are you sure you are using `spark 2.2`? what exactly are you using `alluxio` for ? - if you read/write data: I suggest setting up helper class within `spark` application by passing `master-url` of your `alluxio - master` ex: `val ds = spark.read.parquet(s"alluxio://${master}:19998/${env_param}ds.parquet").as[dsSchema]`

Comment: Yes, I'm using spark 2.2 (Snapshot).  I'm using alluxio as a data caching mechanism.  I have a helper class already which does something very similar to what you mention.  The issue is that when files are written to alluxio, the owner of the files is always the user under which the spark job is submitted, NOT the username I am adding to the configuration.  My understanding is that I should be able to set the user of the files written to spark through the alluxio.security.login.username configuration item.  This configuration item is not being picked up by spark-submit for some reason.

Comment: I have a strong suspicion (based on looking at other posts) that the problem here has to do with the classpath, and how that classpath interacts with the jar file I'm submitting to spark.  But I don't have good visibility into the inner workings of these two.  Is there a debug flag I can pass or some other way to get more information on how the jar is being interpreted by spark-submit?

Comment: yes, I think you are right it most likely it does, if you use it as internal caching mech - disable password all along, and you will avoid the hustle, i have built similar solution without user/pass and it is running in prod for a while with no issues, control access to cluster from outside by vpn, security groups etc

Comment: Got it - thanks for the response.  Often the next best thing to a solution is a recognition that you're not alone :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If spark-submit is in client mode, you should use `--driver-java-options` instead of `--conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=...` in order for the driver JVM to be started with the desired options. Therefore your command would look something like:

`./bin/spark-submit ... --driver-java-options "-Dalluxio.security.login.username=alluxio" ...`

This should start the driver with the desired Java options.

If the Spark executors also need the option, you can set that with:

`--conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dalluxio.security.login.username=alluxio"`