# Pyspark - fpgrowth - association rules - StackOverflow error

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, stack-overflow, apache-spark-sql

I have a huge dataframe (5 million rows) , each row is a basket of items, and I am trying to get the frequent item sets and association rules. But it's giving me StackOverflowErrors, I tried setting the checkpoint directory but it didn't solve the issue. Any idea how to solve this? Thanks a lot in advance

```
fpGrowth = FPGrowth(itemsCol="ARFeatures", minSupport=0.8, minConfidence=0.9)

model = fpGrowth.fit(completeDf)
```

> java.lang.StackOverflowError
>           at java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException.(InvocationTargetException.java:72)
>           at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor14.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1028)
>           at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
>           at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
>           at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
>           at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
>           at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
>           at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
>           at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
>           at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
>           at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$writeObject$1.apply(HashMap.scala:138)
>           at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$writeObject$1.apply(HashMap.scala:136)
>           at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:230)
>           at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40)
>           at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.serializeTo(HashTable.scala:125)
>           at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.serializeTo(HashMap.scala:40)
>           at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.scala:136)
>           at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor14.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1028)
>           at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
>           at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
>           at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
>           at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
>           at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
>           at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
>           at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
>           at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
>           at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$writeObject$1.apply(HashMap.scala:138)

Comment: I don't know the internals of FPGrowth but have you tried increasing the stack size? (JVM option -Xss)

Comment: Is this one of the command line arguments for spark-submit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increase the driver stack size. It depends on how you execute the application, you need to correctly pass the driver JVM option.

For spark-submit you can add it as a cmd line arg:

```
--conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Xss10m"
```

Take a look at these for more details:

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18531
- [How to pass -D parameter or environment variable to Spark job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28166667/how-to-pass-d-parameter-or-environment-variable-to-spark-job)

Comment: "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Xss10m" works for me