# apache spark: add JVM parameter

Tags: java, apache-spark

I want to use jdbc driver with apache spark but there is a strange problem with jdbc that is **Timezone shifts**. This problem explains [here](https://medium.com/@radek.strnad/tips-for-using-jdbc-in-apache-spark-sql-396ea7b2e3d3).

The Solution suggests that we should add this parameter

```
-Duser.timezone=UTC
```

I do some search and I found that I may be set these parameters:

```
spark.driver.extraJavaOptions
spark.executor.extraJavaOptions
```

but I don't Know where should I add it? In the master config files?

```
spark-env.sh
spark-defaults.conf
```

in the slaves config files?

```
spark-env.sh
spark-defaults.conf
```

Or in the SparkConf directly in my application?

Comment: Did you try passing the values in spark-submit command. Please refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28166667/how-to-pass-d-parameter-or-environment-variable-to-spark-job)

Comment: I don't use spark-submit. I use IDE for running job.

Answer (score 0):

You can set it in SparkConf in your application 
or you can also set it in spark-defaults.conf.

Refer https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html for more details.

Comment: spark-defaults.conf in master node or slave nodes? Is there any difference?

Comment: You need to add it in the node from where you trigger the spark-submit. In general ,we do it from the edge node. Are you referring edge node as master node?

Comment: No, I mean by master, node that run spark master jvm. I run my jobs from a remote machine.

Comment: Could you please explain more about edge node? Is this a node in the cluster or out of a cluster?

Comment: It's the node in the cluster. It is the entry point for the cluster and we run our jobs from edge nodes