# Authenticate spark structured streaming against kafka with delegation token, in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, authentication, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I'm trying to stream messages out of kafka with spark structured streaming in scala as per spark [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html) like this:

```
val sparkConfig = new SparkConf()
      .setAppName("Some.app.name")
      .setMaster("local")
        
val spark = SparkSession
      .builder
      .config(sparkConfig)
      .getOrCreate()

val dataframe = spark
     .readStream
     .format("kafka")
     .option("subscribe", kafkaTopic)
     .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafkaEndpoint)
     .option("kafka.security.protocol", "SASL_PLAINTEXT")
     .option("kafka.sasl.username", "$ConnectionString")
     .option("kafka.sasl.password", kafkaConnectionString)
     .option("kafka.sasl.mechanism", "PLAIN")
     .option("spark.kafka.clusters.cluster.sasl.token.mechanism", "SASL_PLAINTEXT")
     .option("includeHeaders", "true")
     .load() 

val outputAllToConsoleQuery = dataframe
    .writeStream
    .format("console")
    .start()
                    
outputAllToConsoleQuery.awaitTermination()
```

Which of course fails with `Could not find a 'KafkaClient' entry in the JAAS configuration. System property 'java.security.auth.login.config' is not set`

As per spark documentation [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#delegation-token) *"..the application can be configured via Spark parameters and may not need JAAS login configuration"*.
I have also read kafka [documentation](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security_delegation_token).
I think I can get the idea, but I haven't found a way to **actually** code it, nor have I found any example.
Could someone provide the code in scala that configures spark structured streaming to authenticate against kafka and use delegation token, without JAAS configuration file?

Comment: `${cluster}` is a placeholder. Should be replaced with an actual value

Comment: identical result...

Comment: Alright, well, I'm not sure this solves anything, but the error `System property 'java.security.auth.login.config' is not set` means you need to provide that flag as a Java option to the executors I think. E.g see for "Spark parameters" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28166667/how-to-pass-d-parameter-or-environment-variable-to-spark-job

Comment: Also see the example at the bottom of the page https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#jaas-login-configuration ... I've not used these properties, but the table discussing delegation tokens seems to say you need another property for bootstrap servers, prefixed by your `spark.kafka.clusters.cluster.`, explicitly referencing the target regex setting in the docs above the table

Comment: @OneCricketeer, thanks, i've kind of descihpered that and tried a few options I've guessed but none worked. At this point I'd need a working example... but haven't been able to find any so far...

Comment: I would think looking into the PR around the feature and the integration tests should give some idea of how it is expected to work (or there is a bug) https://github.com/apache/spark/commit/d47c219f94f478b4b90bf6f74f78762ea301ebf9 And seems you might need as a dependency `spark-token-provider-kafka-0-10_2.12` also the kerberized example https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/DirectKerberizedKafkaWordCount.scala